# Defining Docket bean with multiple string pattern for Swagger documentation

Tags: regex, swagger

I have following code to define Docket for swagger documentation for my rest API in a spring boot application:

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(regex("/((^|, )(api1|api2))+$/.*"))
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
```

My aim is to have endpoints url as `/api1/...` OR `/api2/...`, but it is not working.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you please provide examples of inputs and expected outcomes? Thanks.

Comment: Try `^/api[12]/$` https://regex101.com/r/6BJjpG/1 or `^/api[12]/.*$` if there can be any value after the last forward slash

Comment: api1,api2 is just an example..it can be like this, api,test...so I  tried this on the above site..^/test|api/.*$...this accepts api only , not test. So string after | is accepted, not one before it.

Comment: This works.../(drive|api)/.*